Proof of the Gibbard-Satterthwaite theorem in Osborne and Rubinstein
I'm self-studying Osborne and Rubinstein's Models in Microeconomic Theory and I'm struggling to understand a step in their proof of the Gibbard-Satterthwaite theorem. I won't provide the full proof, but the passages of interest are the two following steps ($f$ denotes a social choice rule):

Step 1: If $f((\succsim^i)_{i \in N}) = x$ and $(\trianglerighteq^i)_{i \in N}$ differs from $(\succsim^i)_{i \in N}$ only in that for some individual $j$ the rank of some alternative $y$ is higher in $\trianglerighteq^j$ than it is in $\succsim^j$, then $f((\trianglerighteq^i)_{i \in N}) \in \{x, y \}$.


Step 2: Let $f((\succsim^i)_{i \in N}) = x$ and let $y$ be another alternative. By Step 1 we have $f((\trianglerighteq^i)_{i \in N}) = x$, where $\trianglerighteq^i$ is obtained from $\succsim^i$ by moving all alternatives except $x$ and $y$ to below these two alternatives (retaining the order of $x$ and $y$).

In Step 2, what allows us to conclude that $f((\trianglerighteq^i)_{i \in N}) = x$ instead of $f((\trianglerighteq^i)_{i \in N}) = y$?

I think I have an answer. It had previously been shown that there exists an individual $i^*$ such that $F((\succsim^i)_{i \in N}) = \succsim^{i^*}$ for any preference profile $(\succsim^i)_{i \in N}$. Now, if we let $f((\succsim^i)_{i \in N}) = x$, that means the only restriction we are imposing on $(\succsim^i)_{i \in N}$ is that not all individuals rank $y$ as the best alternative, because then by unanimity the social choice rule would select $y$. In particular, we are allowing $(\succsim^i)_{i \in N}$ to be a preference profile in which all individuals rank $x$ as the best alternative. Now consider the profile $(\trianglerighteq)_{i \in N}$, which by definition leaves the relative ordering of $x$ and $y$ the same as it is in $(\succsim^i)_{i \in N}$. By Step 1 $f((\trianglerighteq)_{i \in N}) \in \{x, y \}$. If $f((\trianglerighteq)_{i \in N}) = y$, then that would need to hold even in the case where all individuals rank $x$ as the best alternative, thus violating unanimity. Therefore $f((\trianglerighteq)_{i \in N})$.
Does this make sense to you?
